Zariski opens of an affine space and (po)sites
There is a very neat presentation of the Zariski open sets in $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$: it is freely generated (under arbitrary unions and finite intersections, which distribute over each other) by symbols $D(f)$ where $f \in R$, subject to
$$
\begin{aligned}
D\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n f_i\right) &= \bigcap_{i=1}^n D(f_i) \\
D\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n f_i\right) &\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n D(f_i)
\end{aligned}
$$
It is an easy algebra exercise to see that the generated elements are in bijection with radical ideals, and therefore coincide with the textbook Zariski opens.
A Grothendieck (pre)coverage can be thought of as a set of imposed relations when freely generating a topos. This can be decategorized to partial orders: a topos corresponds to a locale, and we can define a coverage on a poset which generates a locale. The elements of the locale are sheaves valued in $\{\top, \bot\}$. Expanding the definitions, we get a subset of the poset which is downwards closed, and if the elements of a cover are in the subset, then the covered element is also in the subset.
Is there a non-trivial way to present $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ in this way? The obvious candidate is to take the poset (actually a preordered set, but it doesn't really matter) of elements ordered by divisibility. But then the finite intersections (which are preserved by yoneda) are then the lcm, which is a priori different from the product. So to make this work we might have to take radicals manually, which would probably give us a trivial presentation.

Hmm, I wonder if in some sense, the sheaves of sets on $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ are the free topos with a distinguished "local ring" object and a ring morphism from $R$ to the global sections of the object?  (Where "local ring" object of a topos would mean that the interpretation of "if $f+g$ is a unit, then $f$ is a unit or $g$ is a unit" is true.)

@DanielSchepler More or less this is true; $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is home to the "generic localization of $R$", the local ring $\mathcal{O}$ together with a localization morphism $\underline{R} \to \mathcal{O}$ (you forgot the localization requirement). The "generic local $R$-algebra", without any localization requirement, also exists, but lives in the big Zariski topos (not the small one), see e.g. Section 12 of my thesis or Section 3 of this survey paper (though these results are not all mine).

(I meant to say "not at all mine". I.e. they are classic results, starting with the PhD thesis of Monique Hakim (only that she didn't have the language of geometric theories available). The appropriate references are cited in those papers)

Yes, and among the concrete presentations of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ it's the one which I personally like best.
As objects for your thin site / preorder, use the elements of $R$. It's prudent to formally write $D(f)$ for the object of the site given by $f \in R$.
Declare that there is a morphism $D(f) \to D(g)$ iff $f \in \sqrt{(g)}$, i.e. iff $f^n = hg$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $h \in R$. (So, not the plain divisibility ordering!)
As coverage, have $(D(f_i) \to D(f))_{i=1,\ldots,n}$ covering iff $\sqrt{(f_i)_i} = \sqrt{(f)}$.
Voilà, you have now constructed $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ without ever going substantially beyond structures of the same size as $R$ (no arbitrary unions, not even finite ones).

Nice, it's better than I thought!
